# How to Add images back after removing them in kivy

Tags: kivy, python-2.x

I am trying to add back the images on the UI once they are all removed, I tried doing add_widget but it threwback this error. I just want to add 10 more images once the previous ten have been removed.

**The error message**

```
<   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1465, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "/home/nabeel/Desktop/widgets.kv", line 25, in <module>
     on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
   File "/home/nabeel/Desktop/widgets.py", line 44, in remove_rectangle
     self.grid_layout.add_widget(widget)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 116, in add_widget
     return super(FloatLayout, self).add_widget(widget, index)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 81, in add_widget
     return super(Layout, self).add_widget(widget, index)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 453, in add_widget
     % (widget, parent))
 kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.factory.ImgButton object at 0x7f580b454258>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.floatlayout.FloatLayout object at 0x7f580b44f4c8>
>
```

**The .py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

import random

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '320')


running = True


class MyWidget(AnchorLayout):

    LOC = []
    for i in range (10):
        LOC.append((random.randint(0,400),random.randint(0,300)))

    num = 9

    b_G_IMG = StringProperty("B_image.png")
    time = 40
    time_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time_number = str(self.time)

    def remove_rectangle(self, widget):
        if self.num > 1:
            self.grid_layout.remove_widget(widget)
            self.set_level()
            self.num -= 1
        else:
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(widget)
            self.num = 9



    def call(self):
        if True:
            self.time += 1
            print(self.time)
            self.time_number = str(self.time)           
    def clicked(self):
        #global running
        #self.time_number = 50
        running=False

    Clock.schedule_interval(call, 1)

class WidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    WidgetsApp().run()
```

**The .kv file**

```
<ImgButton@Button>:

    size_hint:(None,None)
    size:(60,60)

<MyWidget>:
    grid_layout: grid_layout
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            Image:
                source:root.b_G_IMG
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:root.time_number
        FloatLayout:

            id: grid_layout

            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[0])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[1])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[2])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)    
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[3])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[4])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[5])                   
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[6])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[7])
                background_normal: 'image.png'    
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[8])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[9])
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to add back the same widget that is calling remove_rectangle, you need to create a new widget in remove_rectangle. Do something like

```
class ImgButton(Button):
    pass



def remove_rectangle(self, widget):
    ...
    else:
        new_image = ImgButton(background_normal='image.png')

        self.grid_layout.add_widget(new_image)
```

Comment: It Does work But Then I tried to refine my code by adding a for loop in the __init__ of my MyWidget function that adds 9 instances of the ImgButton objects using the above method, but then I have trouble referencing it to remove_rectangle(widget=self) function.

Comment: You need to bind the new_image to an on_press function that removes the widget... `new_image.bind(on_press=remove_rectangle)`. See kivy's bind docs.